# QtWebKit - Userscript/Javascript Injection

Tags: javascript, python, qtwebkit, userscripts, spynner

I've been doing testing work in Python using QtWebkit/Spynner. As QtWebKit has Javascript support just like Chrome's Webkit, is it possible to inject a userscript or a piece of javascript at **the beginning of a page** just like you would a regular user script in Chrome?

Hopefully a simple question for those experience! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

1. Register a handler for [`QWebPage.frameCreated`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebpage.html#frameCreated)
2. Inside that event handler, register a new event handler for [`QWebFrame.javaScriptWindowObjectCleared`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebframe.html#javaScriptWindowObjectCleared)
3. In that second event handler, use [`QWebFrame.evaluateJavaScript`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript) (or Spynner's `runjs` method) to run your Javascript.

This is the approach taken by [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/master/src/WebPage.cpp) to execute its utility scripts. Unfortunately I can't give you example Python code because I'm not familiar with the Qt Python bindings.

Answer (score 1):

From the previous answer (Niklas B.):
the capybara-webkit uses a not so useful double subscription of signal-slot (frameCreated-javaScriptWindowObjectCleared), and uses a sender() call in the injectJavascriptHelpers() function that is not a good practice for a decoupled code.

Actually you only need to connect the "javaScriptWindowObjectCleared" signal from the mainFrame() to your slot.

Supposing you are using the *old* Widget coding style for PyQt (no qml then):

```
class InstrumentedPage(PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets.QWebPage):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.finished)
        self.mainFrame().javaScriptWindowObjectCleared.connect(self.initYourJavascriptAtTheBeginningHere)

    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
        message = "%s (%s:%d)" % (message, sourceID, lineNumber)
        self.__logger.info("JS :: %s" % message )

    def initYourJavascriptAtTheBeginningHere(self):
        js = "console.log(\"INITED\");"
        self.mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(js)

    def injectYourJavascriptHere(self, js):
        return self.mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(js)

    def finished(self, status):
        self.__logger.info("InstrumentedPage.finished() :: init status => %s" % status)

class MainWindow(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, config, config_file_name, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi( self )

        self.web_page = InstrumentedPage()
        self.ui.webView.setPage(self.web_page)
```